# What does perf interrupt mean?

Tags: kernel, dmesg, events

I am working on my computer, trying to write some device code.
I checked into dmesg to get some info, and saw this:

```
perf interrupt took too long (2507 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

what does this event mean? Cause? Concern?

Comment: I had similar message as last one in `journalctl` before sudden reboot happened while I was watching YouTube.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should not be a concern. [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a tool to handle CPU performance. The kernel is capable of automatically determining the sample rate without affecting the performance of the system. [Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187636) is a thread on this from the Arch forum.

Comment: would it make a difference if I switch to another clock source like the HPET?

Comment: What does "sample rate" refer to in this case?

Answer (score 13):

[This answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187636) from the Arch Forum sums it up:

> This message is informational and nothing to worry about.
>
> It has to do with the Linux [perf tool](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) which is included in the kernel. The kernel automagically determines the sample rate that could be used without impacting system performance too much; and it logs this even when perf isn't active, or even installed.
>
> Messages like this are triggered by high(er) system load or [a cpu that is scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_scaling).

Comment: I got this after doing I/O benchmarking combined with repated sync. Nothing to worry about as long as numbers after `interrupt took too long (3979 > 3930)` are close enough. If the bigger one is say 10x the another then you may have some problems with CPU scheduling.

Comment: I often get this BS while gaming which causes lag spikes and other issues. Super obnoxious as the game will hang for a second, perf interrupt message will pop up in dmesg and then the game will snap back but any mouse/movement input during that moment is super exaggerated...it's fun flying into the side of a mountain for no reason...ug.