# Stuck after login (frezee after login screen)

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

I have a problem with my Ubuntu (14.04 LTS). My computer become crash after login (it took about 3-5 minutes to login). After that, It operated at very low speed.

The solutions I tried (and not working are) :

- Reinstall Ubuntu (even a new version 16.04 LTS had the same problem).
- Reboot and use boot repair USB disk ( It's fine after 1st reboot, but for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... The reboot stuck at login screen again)
- Reinstall newest version graphic driver

My laptop details:

- HP EliteBook 840
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- OS type: 64-bit
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/24096630/

I took too much time in this issue, maybe somebody has a little insight, any help would be appreciated, thanks so much

Comment: The time to login is excessive. My best guess based on the information provided is a failing hard disk. I recommend that you [check the SMART status of your drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-10/528077#528077) as it sounds like the root cause may be excessive retries accessing the disk.

Comment: Thank @Elder Geek
I already checked the status of my hard disk, there is not any problems. 
So I use dmesg to screen out my reboot process:

Comment: **dmesg** to screen out my reboot process:

`[  201.963370] perf: interrupt took too long (2527 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000


[  341.813119] perf: interrupt took too long (3214 > 3158), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62000


[  933.817145] perf: interrupt took too long (4078 > 4017), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49000


[ 1042.969274] perf: interrupt took too long (5238 > 5097), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 38000`

Comment: I don't think that's relevant to your problem and I would assume there is more to your reboot than what you have represented here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/621490/what-does-perf-interupt-mean If you have information to add to your post you should [edit] it into your post as comments can be deleted for a number of reasons.