# Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 massive slow down

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, ubuntu-budgie

Laptop: ASUS Sonic Master E4003S with 4 GB RAM

Issue: Massive slowdowns since upgrading to Ubuntu Budgie 19.10. Machine takes literally 310 seconds (= 5 mins and 10 secs) to respond to any click or keystroke. Cursor freezes; keyboard nonresponsive. Checked logs for insights.

Kernel log error:

```
perf: interrupt took too long (10512 > 9967), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 19000
```

For @heynnema...

`free -h`:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       2.2Gi       182Mi       545Mi       1.4Gi       758Mi
Swap:         3.9Gi       223Mi       3.7Gi
```

`sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: E403SA.300
       date: 06/01/2016
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT425S6CFR6A-PB
          vendor: Hynix Semiconduc
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM0
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: Array1_PartNumber1
          vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
          physical id: 1
          serial: A1_SerNum1
          slot: A1_DIMM1
          size: 2GiB
          width: 16 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: CPU Internal L1
       size: 224KiB
       capacity: 224KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: CPU Internal L2
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
```

Comment: According to this answer this very error is nothing to worry about : https://askubuntu.com/questions/621490/what-does-perf-interupt-mean , so You probably have some other issue here.

Comment: You can try kernel version previous to update: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184366/lagging-after-update-to-19-10-from-19-04/1184571#1184571

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: @hyennema : Ty! Done! I seem to have adequate RAM & hardware memory. Very grateful for your observations.

Comment: D'oh! Typo! Sorry. Ty @heynnema

Comment: I went to the ASUS web site and couldn't find your model #, but I did find a E403SA, and there appears to be a newer BIOS available at https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-E403SA/HelpDesk_Download/. Do you have a VivoBook or a laptop? Make good backups, update your BIOS, and lets see if that helps. If not, I've got some thinking about your memory that we'll talk about. Report back.

Comment: The BIOS flash utility is at https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeeBook/Apps_for_Win10/Winflash/Winflash_Win10_64_VER310.zip?_ga=2.26007614.249428055.1573921423-412764563.1573741584, and the BIOS 301 is at https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeeBook/E403SA/E403SAAS301zip.zip?_ga=2.196991407.249428055.1573921423-412764563.1573741584 (actually, it looks like they list EeeBook and VivoBook on separate web pages, so make sure you get the correct one).

Comment: I have exactly the same pb, did you resolve yours ?