# Reboot stucked with perf: interrupt took too long (3141 > 3135), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500

Tags: command-line

I need help to this problem, I ave never came across this before, rebooting my PC stucked with a screen containing the subject text,

```
perf: interrupt took too long (3141 > 3135), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
```

please what does this means and how can I resolved the issues.

Thanks for anticipated response.

Comment: That message is not that unusual, and by itself doesn't really help to isolate the issue. For example here is one from my computer `Jul 31 13:58:35 s19 kernel: [592608.446947] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000` but everything was actually fine, although I assume somewhat busy at the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does perf interrupt mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621490/what-does-perf-interrupt-mean)